# How to make oh-my-zsh path display on macOS case sensitive?

Tags: macos, zsh, oh-my-zsh

Oh-my-zsh on macOS case-insensitive filesystem displays the `actual path` relative to how you type it.

I was wondering can I make it display `~/Test` even if I type `cd test`.

Image:

[image]